# Can this category be identified as the category of graphs?

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathbb I$ be a category with exactly $2$ objects and $4$ arrows. The $2$ arrows that are not identities are parallel and their (common) domain and (common) codomain are distinct. Looking at the category  $$\mathsf Set^{\mathbb I}$$
(having as objects the functors $\mathbb I\rightarrow\mathsf Set$ and as arrows the natural transformations) I wondered if this category can be recognized as the category of (small) graphs. Is that indeed the case, or am I overlooking something?

---

If I am right here then the fact that $\mathsf Set$ is (co)complete justifies the the conclusion that $\mathsf Grph$ is (co)complete.

Comment: A functor $\Bbb I\to\mathbf{Set}$ is then determined by the choice of two isomorphic sets and one bijection between them. $\mathbf{Set}^{\Bbb I}$ is just the category of bijections, whose arrows are the set maps which are compatible with these bijections.

Comment: @StefanHamcke That would be so if the non-identities are inverses of eachother right? But they are not. They are parallel.

Comment: The answer depends on what you mean by "graph". Do you allow more than one edge between two vertices? Do you allow an edge with both ends the same vertex? etc.

Comment: Lets call the objects $x$ and $y$, and the arrows $i:x\to y$ and $j:y\to x$. Then $j\circ i$ must be the unique arrow $1:x\to x$.

Comment: @StefanHamcke Parallel also means that the orientations are the same.

Comment: @ZhenLin By a graph I am thinking of two sets $A$ (arrows) and $O$ (objects) and two functions $A\rightarrow O$ (domain and codomain). As can be found in e.g. CWM.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the question. I interpreted "their domains and codomains are distinct" as $dom(i)\ne dom(j)$ and $cod(i)\ne cod(j)$.

Comment: But then $i,j:x\to y$, is that what you mean?

Comment: @StefanHamcke As you understand now the word 'distinct' was used to say that the arrows are not endomorphisms. $i,j:x\rightarrow y$ is indeed what I mean.

Comment: @H.B. Then yes, what you have is the category of graphs, almost by definition.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thank you. I thought so, but in cases like this confirmations are very welcome. I have not much trust in myself. A consequence is that Grph is (co)complete simply because Set is (co)complete. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.